# VB.NET DateTime from seconds only

Tags: vb.net, frameworks

I would like to get a time (for example 03:00:03) feeding only the seconds, but nothing else.

Using the Microsoft.VisualBasic runtime, I could say

```
 Dim sTimeRemaining As String = DateAndTime.TimeSerial(0, 0, iSecondsRemaining)
```

I would use this to show the user how long a download is still going to take.

Can somebody tell me how to do this without the Microsoft.VisualBasic runtime?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
Dim sTimeRemaining As Date = New Date().AddSeconds(iSecondsRemaining)
```

Note that you should set `Option Strict` to `On`. Then your code wouldn't compile since [`DateAndTime.TimeSerial`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.dateandtime.dateserial%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a `Date` and not a `String`. But it's a good thing because you are forced to build more robust and type safe code.

Perhaps it would also be better to use a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of a `Date` in this case.

```
Dim seconds = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(iSecondsRemaining)
```

Comment: I love you! How do you know all these conversion inside out? I use these 2-3 times within 10 years. Where do you work that you are so familiar with these conversions?

Comment: @tmighty: nothing special, just 12 years .NET.

Comment: Did you do VB6 before these 12 years?

Comment: @tmighty: no, Java and PHP. I have few experiences in VB6 since i neeeded to maintain legacy stuff and some excel VBA.

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice comment. Nice to see somebody who could be a model and also does programming :-)